# How to get focus to GridView First Image Android?

Tags: android

HI,

Iam writing GridView by using BaseAdapter with 2 columns.Each column with One Image and Text.It works smoothly.I had given focus by using below code in onConfig...

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    gridview.requestFocusFromTouch();
    gridview.setSelection(0);
}
```

It works when my view configuration changes.But Same doesn't work in onCreate() method.
I used below all methods in onCreate() but my view doesn;t get focus.How to give focus for the first image when running my application.I want focus on first image when view inflates on the device.Please give me guidance?

```
gridview.requestFocus();
gridview.requestFocusFromTouch();
gridview.setSelected(true);
gridview.setSelection(0);
gridview.setFocusable(true);
gridview.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
gridview.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
```

Regards,
Rajendar Are

Comment: Hi Rajendar I tried that before with no success :(
see this thread :: [GridView: how to select, programmatically?](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/f08a58167dbaa8c8?pli=1 )

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
    mGridView.setSelection(iPos-1);
    mGridView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    mGridView.setSelection(iPos-1);
```

Unknown why have to do it twice:

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you can do like this：

"sleep" little time

```
        Thread.sleep(1);

        gridview.requestFocusFromTouch();
        gridview.setSelection(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by just calling mGridView.setSelected(true); in onResume()
In this way my 1st element has got the selection.

Now I'm looking for ways how to set selection for random element